# jqgrid undefined integer? pager not loading

Tags: json, jqgrid, pagination

IM using jqgrids on mvc4, I need to get a simple list and display it using Ajax.

When I load the page then grid starts an Ajax call, I have only 2 columns on grid, user_id and name.

When the Json is loaded I get the next error on Google chrome:

**Uncaught Typesetter: Cannot read property 'integer' of undefined**

and in firefox, firebug:

**TypeError: b.jgrid.formatter is undefined**

on jquery.jqGrid.src.js:122

And the grid shows an "undefined" msg, also, the current pageer control isnt loading, but the data is

```
 <table id="GridUsuarios"></table>
    <div id="PagerUsuarios"></div>


  <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#GridUsuarios").jqGrid({
                url: '@Url.Action("UsuariosGridData","Usuarios")',
                datatype: "json",
                myType: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",                
                colNames: ['Usuario', 'Nombre'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'user_id', index: 'user_id', width: 90},
                    { name: 'nombre', index: 'nombre', width: 200}
                ],
                pager: '#PagerUsuarios',
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                viewrecords: true,
                height: 'auto',
                sortname: 'nombre',
                sortorder: 'desc',
                caption: "Usuarios",
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "rows",
                    total: "total",
                    page: "page",
                    records: "records",
                    repeatitems: false,
                    id: "user_id"
                },
            });            
        });
    </script>
```

and my controller:

```
    public JsonResult UsuariosGridData(string sidx = "" , string sord = "", int page = 1, int rows = 10)
    {
        var resultado = db_hms.Users//.OrderByDescending(ur => ur.id_user)
                        .Join(db_hms.v_natural_person_short, ur => ur.id_employee, np => np.id_natural_person, (ur, np) => new { Users = ur, Natural_Person = np })//cambiar el idUser por idEmployee la relacion es alrevez XD                            
                        .Select(s => new { user_id = s.Users.id_user, nombre = s.Natural_Person.name_full })
                        .ToList();



        int vpage = page;
        int vrows = rows;  
        int counter = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)resultado.Count() / (float)vrows);            
        switch (sidx)
        {
            case "nombre":
                {
                            if(sord == "desc")
                            {
                                resultado = resultado.OrderByDescending(s => s.nombre).Skip(vrows * vpage).Take(vrows).ToList();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                resultado = resultado.OrderBy(s => s.nombre).Skip(vrows * vpage).Take(vrows).ToList(); ;
                            }
                    break;
                }
            case "user_id":
                {
                            if(sord == "desc")
                            {
                                resultado = resultado.OrderByDescending(s => s.user_id).Skip(vrows * vpage).Take(vrows).ToList();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                resultado = resultado.OrderByDescending(s => s.user_id).Skip(vrows * vpage).Take(vrows).ToList();
                            }
                    break;
                }
        }
        var retornar = new
        {
            total = counter,
            page = vpage,
            records = vrows,
            rows = resultado
        };

        return Json(retornar, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

and a small json example:

```
{"total":101,"page":1,"records":303,
 "rows":[{"user_id":"titito","nombre":"EL bonito, tito "},
        {"user_id":"noro","nombre":"ElMoro, Noro "},
        {"user_id":"maka","nombre":"Martinez, Macanencio "}]}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

One get the error message typically if one don't included required language file `grid.locale-XX.js` (for example `grid.locale-en.js`) *before* `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. See the example of the usage of jqGrid in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid#html_file).

Additionally I would recommend you to add `gridview: true` and `autoencode: true` option to jqGrid, remove non-existing `myType: 'GET'` (there are `mtype` option which default value if `"GET"`), reduce `jsonReader` to `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "user_id"}`, remove all `index` properties from `colModel` (because you use the values the same as the value of `name` property) and add `key: true` to definition of `'user_id'` column.

Because you don't implemented server side paging of data I would recommend you add additionally `loadonce: true` option. It allows you to return **all data** at once from `UsuariosGridData` and jqGrid will implement client side sorting, paging or optionally filtering/searching of data.

Comment: cant get it to worck, this is my BundleConfig:             bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqgrid").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js",
                        "~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locate-es.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"));             bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/jquery.jqgrid/jqgridui").Include(
                        "~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css"));

Comment: and on the layout         @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")         @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqgrid")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

Comment: @EricGS: You are welcome! You don't need to include `"~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js"` if `"~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"` or `"~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"` is included. So one should just include `"~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locate-es.js"` and then for example `"~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"`.

Comment: Once again, Oleg to our rescue!

Comment: Good catch @Oleg . I added your solution to blog: http://blog.webdevilopers.net/jqgrid-typeerror-b-jgrid-formatter-is-undefined/ Thanks!

Comment: Four years later and I'm still using jqGrid.  This solution actually worked for me, although I was dubious. Problem solved.  Thank you.

Comment: @RodHartzell: You are welcome! Which version of jqGrid you use from from which *fork* of jqGrid? The fork [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) don't need to include `grid.locale-en.js`. The current version of free jqGrid is 4.15.3.

Comment: Outstanding!  I will switch to free jqGrid immediately.

Comment: @RodHartzell: In the case I'd recommend you to look through [the page](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html), some [wiki articles](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and probably the READMEs of old releases of free jqGrid (for example the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/su7ebs65/ is included in README of version 4.14.1).

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to the *jqgrid locale* file first followed by *jqrid*

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqgrid/4.6.0/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
```