# jqGrid: Not loading when pager set and array data used, why?

Tags: jqgrid

I am using array data to load a jqGrid with support for pagination. Without the pager property set, the grid loads the data, and looks like this:

[image]

The blue bar at the bottom is the pager element. But if the pager property is set, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'integer' of undefined jquery.jqGrid.min.js:131
> a.updatepager jquery.jqGrid.min.js:131
> U jquery.jqGrid.min.js:67
> M jquery.jqGrid.min.js:81
> (anonymous function) jquery.jqGrid.min.js:135
> jQuery.extend.each jquery-1.10.2.min.js:657
> jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery-1.10.2.min.js:266
> b.fn.jqGrid jquery.jqGrid.min.js:33
> createGrid
```

Please help me find what I am doing wrong.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <table id=grid></table>
    <div id=grid_pager></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function createGrid(dataAsArray) {
    $('#grid').jqGrid({
        caption: caption,
        colModel: getColumnModel(),

        scrollOffset: 0,
        hidegrid: true,
        sortorder: 'desc',
        recreateForm: true,
        height: '100%',

        pager: '#grid_pager'
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 40, 80],
        viewrecords: true,
        multiselect: true,

        datatype: 'local',
        data: dataAsArray,
        localReader: {
            repeatitems: true,
            cell: '',
            id: 0
        }
    }); 

    $('#grid').jqGrid('navGrid', { edit: true, add: false, del: false, position: 'left' });

    .jqGrid('setGridParam', {
        rowNum: 5,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 30, 100, 500]
    }).trigger('reloadGrid');
}
```

**ARRAY DATA**

```
[
    [ 246802, 'ab', 2, 'Invalid amount' ],
    [ '', 12, 3, 'Invalid account' ],
    ...
]
```

Your help is highly appreciated!

Thanks
Vivek Ragunathan

Comment: I think that including `grid.locale-en.js` (like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16718385/315935) for example) solve your problem. Isn't so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such error occurs typically if one forget to include `grid.locale-en.js` (or some other file from `i18n` directory). The file is really required for jqGrid. You should include it before `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` (or alternatively `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`). If you forgot to include `grid.locale-en.js` then [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.4/js/grid.base.js#L1801)

```js
fmt = $.jgrid.formatter.integer || {};
```

will produce the error which you described because `$.jgrid.formatter` stay undefined (it will be defined [in the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.4/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js#L89)) and the expression `$.jgrid.formatter.integer` will generate the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pager: $('#grid_pager'),
```

Hope it helps.