# How to add functionalty in the JQGridview

Tags: php, jquery, gridview, jqgrid, concrete5

Hi I working in the concrete5 CMS, its zend based cms framework and mvc pattern

I try to manipulate my data into the jqgridview, it returns data in the gridview but pagination is not working and i don't know how to add the edit, delete and find function in the jqgridview
and also i get "undefined" error in the center of the gridview

script:

```
$(function() {

    $("#eList").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: <?php echo json_encode($emplist) ?>,
        pager: true,
        colNames:['Emp ID','Name','Email', 'Role', 'Contact No','Status'], 
        colModel:[ 
            {name:'emp_id',index:'emp_id', width:55}, 
            {name:'emp_name',index:'emp_name', width:90, editable:true}, 
            {name:'uEMail',index:'uEMail', width:100}, 
            {name:'role_name',index:'role_name', width:80, align:"right"}, 
            {name:'emp_contact_no',index:'emp_contact_no', width:80, align:"right",editable:true}, 
            {name:'status_name',index:'status_name', width:80,align:"right"}
        ],
        rowNum:5, 
        rowList:[5,10,20], 
        pager : '#ePage',
        sortname: 'emp_name', 
        viewrecords: true, 
        sortorder: "desc",
        editurl: "local", 
        caption: "Using navigator" 
    });

    $("#eList").jqGrid('navGrid',selector,options,pEdit,pAdd,pDel,pSearch ); 

    $("#eList").jqGrid('navGrid',"#ePage",{edit:true,add:true,del:true}); 

    $("#eList").jqGrid('inlineNav',"#ePage");
});
```

html

```
<table id = "eList" >
</table>
<div id = "ePage" >
</div>
```

please suggest me how to add the functionality, or any good example or demo of jqgrid or any link related to learn the jqgrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use *local* paging of data the server (`<?php echo json_encode($emplist) ?>`) should returns *all* data and you should include the option `loadonce: true`. I recommend you to use additionally the options `gridview: true` and `autoencode: true`. I recommend you remove all `index` properties from `colModel` and add `key: true` option to the definition of the `emp_id` column if it's values are unique and so it can be used as rowids (the values of `id` attribute of `<tr>` elements).

You should remove the line `$("#eList").jqGrid('navGrid',selector,options,pEdit,pAdd,pDel,pSearch );` which contains undefined variables.

Comment: hi i already read most of your answer and demo pages about the jqgrid. In my code just show the value in the gridview thats it. if add pager: true, pager : '#ePage', this two line. it show undifined

Comment: first i want know which are the js and css file to add for this jqgrid

Comment: @KumarShanmugam: About CSS and JS files see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file). Adding `pager: true` is wrong. Adding two properties twice like `pager: true, pager : '#ePage'` is wrong too. I recommend you to open the page in debugger. For example you can use Internet Explorer, press F12 to start developer tools, go to "Script" subtitle and then start "Start debugging" button. It allows you to **see the line** with undefined error.

Comment: TypeError: $.jgrid.formatter is undefined
fmt = $.jgrid.formatter.integer || {}; I got this error when i using pager.

Comment: @KumarShanmugam: It means that you forgot to include `i18n/grid.locale-en.js` before (`jquery.jqGrid.min.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`). See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21139665/315935)

Comment: thanks a lot @Oleg, its working fine... superb.. i spend last two days for this solution... just add the js file its work properly... thank you so much... i want to workout more on this jqgrid.. may be i need more help from you..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46242/discussion-between-kumar-shanmugam-and-oleg)